# How to read an element attribute with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to find all tags in an html page that have the text "About".
To get that result i used this:

```
text = page.body.find(string=re.compile('About'))
parent=about.parent
link=parent.href
```

`text` is a list of 8 letters forming the phrase "About me", which is surprising to me. Even more surprising is that if i print `text` the result is the phrase "About me" with no gaps, as it weren't a list but a single variable.

The variable `parent` results in this:

```
<a class="menu__link" href="/about-us" title="">About Us</a>
```

As you can see, the parents(a tags) have a *href* attribute. But the variable "link" results in None instead of the *href* attribute.
What is going on?

Please ask if anything is not clear

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO.

If I understand your question correctly, you're not sure how to access an attribute of an element.

This should do the trick:

```
link = parent['href']
```

Happy coding :)